# AngularJS - How to restrict scope on ngClick in multiple instances

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to create a single directive that will toggle an element open or closed when a trigger link is clicked.  However, when one trigger is clicked, it toggles all the instances open rather than a single one.

My code looks like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/IA1hrbAoUEvvkwDjRAh6

Can anyone help to explain how to make this work with attributes and without defining my templates in the directives themselves?

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive just read the whole thing, especially *Directive Definition Object -> scope*

Comment: Yes, the documentation is the first place I looked, but it's fairly confusing stuff.  Examples are always better for me, so that's why I'm reaching out to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using the one single instance of `PancelCtrl` for the three panels. So, the directive never know which panel should be toggled because it's not specified anywhere.

You have two different options:

Create a single instance for every `li` element:

```
<!-- (you have to remove 'data-ng-controller="PanelCtrl"' from 'div.subfooter') -->
<li data-ng-controller="PanelCtrl">
  <a ng-click="toggle()" href="#">Panel A</a></a>
  <div data-panel-trigger data-visible="visibility" class="panel span2">
    <p>Panel Content</p>
  </div>
</li>
<li data-ng-controller="PanelCtrl">
  <a ng-click="toggle()" href="#">Panel B</a>
  <div data-panel-trigger data-visible="visibility" class="panel span2">
    <p>Panel Content</p>
  </div>
</li>
<li data-ng-controller="PanelCtrl">
  <a ng-click="toggle()" href="#">Panel C</a>
  <div data-panel-trigger data-visible="visibility" class="panel span2">
    <p>Panel Content</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Doing that, you'll have three `PanelCtrl` instances, and every one will toggle the child element that responds to it.

The other option, is to check which panel is next to the clicked link (using jQuery it's done with something like `$(this).siblings("div")`). But I think that the first one will be more suitable, as you'll encapsulate the code behavior for every panel you want to add on the site.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for—how to avoid using something like `$(this).siblings("div")` or relying too much on a specific DOM structure.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working plunk that does what you want:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HcoyFyCSnrfmLu3lI7a6

The advantage here is that the directive is completely self contained, each one has it's own scope object.  Note you don't even need a controller anymore.

See also: http://www.egghead.io/video/fYgdU7u2--g

Your new directive definition:

```
app.directive('panelTrigger', function() {
    return {
      scope:{},
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

        $scope.toggle = function() {
           $scope.visibility = !$scope.visibility;
        };

        // Default visibility is false
        $scope.visibility = false;

        $scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function( newValue, oldValue ) {

          if ( newValue === oldValue ) {
              return;
          }

          var elm = angular.element(element.children()[1]);
          if (newValue) {
            elm.attr('style', 'display: block;');
          } else {
            elm.attr('style', 'display: none;');
          }
        });
      }
    };
})
```

And a small change to your html:

```
      <div data-panel-trigger data-visible="visibility">
        <a ng-click="toggle()" href="#">Panel A</a>
        <div class="panel span2">
          <p>Panel Content</p> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because they are all affecting the same scope. Add

```
scope:{
  ...
  ...
 }
```

To your directive definition and use bind attributes to your directive scope as needed.